# Google Cloud Function : Custom Domain via FIrebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I know this is already discussed. But need to get a few more specifics.

What I have done :

1. Connected my Google Cloud Project with firebase from https://console.firebase.google.com
2. This automatically imported the cloud functions in the google project to the firebase functions section

[image: The functions listing in firebase]

3. Next I checked whether this function (function name is 'function1', the runtime is python) is available at https://project-id.firebaseapp.com/function-1 or https://project-id.web.app.com/function-1. But it says the following:

[image]

This I understand is because I have not run `firebase deploy --only hosting`.

4. But I can only run these commands from the firebase terminal. But this I feel should have the code in my local machine. Here I don't have any code to deploy. The function is already listed in the firebase project.

Help Required:

So how should I deploy this? Isn't this function already deployed? Because the google cloud function is available at https://us-central1-google-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/function-1?

Once I get the function running at https://project-id.web.app.com/function-1, I believe that if I add a custom domain, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

So after playing around I found the specifics to deploy an already existing GCP cloud function via firebase, which in turn can be used to connect a custom domain to it

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/  and in the text box, you will be able to select your existing GCP. This will list your GCP function in firebase
2. Next go to [https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{project-id}/hosting](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/%7Bproject-id%7D/hosting) and click on get started.
3. In your local machine, create a folder. Do firebase login. Then do firebase init. Here they ask you for many options. Select ONLY the hosting option
4. Once that completes, you can see that the link https://project-id.web.app.com is working now
5. Now you want to connect the URL to the existing cloud function
6. For that follow step 3 in https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions where you edit a local file created called firebase.json to link the required URL path to your cloud function name
7. Now you will see that the function is hosted in https://project-id.web.app.com/function-1
8. To add a custom domain, follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Comment: Important note: "Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only"